# Does escapeSingleQuotes esacpe backslash too?

Tags: soql, soql-injection

Does `escapeSingleQuotes` escape backslash character too?

From the [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm) it mentions:

> If you must use dynamic SOQL, use the escapeSingleQuotes method to sanitize user-supplied input. This method adds the escape character () to all single quotation marks in a string that is passed in from a user. The method ensures that all single quotation marks are treated as enclosing strings, instead of database commands.

However if this only escapes single quote, in theory it does not prevent all kinds of SQL injections. For example,

1. I can have this as string: `test\'@gmail.com`.
2. `escapeSingleQuotes` will turn this into `test\\'@gmail.com`
3. When this is appended to the query:

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Email = 'test\\'@gmail.com'
```

Backslash character will also need to be escaped to prevent this. If `escapeSingleQuotes` does escape backslashes too, it may be less confusing if the official document can be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does escape the backslash before single quote. You should check documentation of [escapeSingleQuotes(stringToEscape)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)

Below is how apex modifies the string - run it in anonymous apex and play-around

```
String s1 = 'a\'d';
System.debug(s1);
System.debug(String.escapeSingleQuotes(s1));
System.assertEquals('a\\\'d', String.escapeSingleQuotes(s1));
System.debug('a\\\'d' == String.escapeSingleQuotes(s1)); //true
System.debug('a\'d'== String.escapeSingleQuotes(s1)); //false

String s2 = 'a\"p';
System.debug(s2);
System.debug(String.escapeSingleQuotes(s2));
System.assertEquals('a"p', String.escapeSingleQuotes(s2));
```

For every single quote and backslash, it will add an extra backslash. Check below in anonymous:

```
String s1 = 'a\'d';
System.debug('a\\\\\\\'d' == String.escapeSingleQuotes(String.escapeSingleQuotes(s1))); //true
```

Comment: Thanks, it's just that the official documentation (including the one you posted) didn't explictly mention escaping backslash.

Comment: Your example does not really test for backslashes however: it is just a `a'd` string. What I want to know would be what happens to escaping `'a\\\'d'`.

Comment: @lulalala, there is no need for explicitly mentioning it as that is how it is supposed to work or else as you said in question, it will break. I added one more example for your understanding. Hope it will be clear now.

Comment: Thanks. It is however important for people implementing similar things in other languages.

Comment: For anyone who comes upon this page, note that backslashes get escaped by escapeSingleQuote() even if there is no single quote:

    string s = 'George\\_Tasker';
    system.debug('BEFORE:' + s);
    system.debug('AFTER: ' + string.escapeSingleQuotes(s));

Before: George\\_Tasker
After: George\\\_Tasker